# How to make a timestamp column immutable in Laravel 7 migration?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

I am working on a project and want to make a timestamp column in the database immutable. In Symfony, I know how to do that, but in Laravel, I don't understand.

```php
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('verification_code')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('accept_policy_at');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: mysql does not support immutable columns, and so your migration even if there might be some method that looks like it will do it, it won't work (you can do something with triggers DB-side, or accessor in the model)

Comment: There are no any way to immutable column in sql. But you can create `accept_policy_at` once, then dont update this.  As like `created_at` column in laravel, this column field never updated, after it inserted on table.

Comment: thx for yout tips! :-)